# Adding numbers from the result of a grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I run the following command:

```
grep -o "[0-9] errors" verification_report_3.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

and I get the following result:

```
1
4
0
8
```

I'd like to add each of the numbers up to a running count variable.  Is there a magic one liner someone can help me build?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
grep -o "[0-9] errors" verification_report_3.txt | awk '{ SUM += $1} END { print SUM }'
```

That doesn't print the list but does print the sum. If you want both the list and the sum, you can do:

```
grep -o "[0-9] errors" verification_report_3.txt | awk '{ SUM += $1; print $1} END { print SUM }'
```

Comment: Shawn - thank you for your answer.  How do I return total back to the bash script out of awk?

Comment: @Amir You would use the first one like this `variable=$(grep -o "[0-9] errors" verification_report_3.txt | awk '{ SUM += $1} END { print SUM }')` This puts the output of the command (which is only the sum value) into the variable called `variable`

Comment: @Amir Afghani Also, you might want to change your grep to `"[0-9]\+ errors"`. This will match if you have a line reporting >9 errors.

Comment: Yup, wow I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you.

Comment: Shawn, the output seems like it's not adding up my results.  It looks like this:  Total Errors = +259+7581+8852+2014+3189++13572+11438+++6+4172+

Comment: And I'm doing this:
    errors=$(grep -o "[0-9]\+ errors" $1 | awk '{ SUM += $1} END { print SUM }');
    totalErrors=${errors}+${totalErrors};

Comment: nm, I got it.      totalErrors=$(($totalErrors + errors))

Comment: The problem there is your expression. with `totalErrors=${errors}+${totalErrors}, you're creating a string. You can do the same trick: echo both numbers as a list and use awk to sum them, or you can do it the [bash way](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/arithmetic_expressions.shtml).

Answer (score 13):

This can all be done in awk as well:

```
awk '"[0-9]+ errors" {sum += $1}; END {print sum}' verification_report_3.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

You appear to be using *GNU* system, so if *Perl* regular expressions support is available,
you could write something like this:

```
grep -Po '[0-9]+(?=\s+errors)' infile | 
  paste -sd+ | 
    bc
```

P.S. I modified the regular expression (added the + quantifier) to allow numbers > 9.

P.S. Alternatively, awk is sufficient (assuming *GNU awk*):

```
awk 'END { print s }
/[0-9]+[[:space:]]+errors/ { 
  s += $1 
  }' infile
```

Comment: the first one for me just prints what already went into the pipe...

Answer (score 4):

I use this:

```
$ echo $(cat file | sed 's/$/+/') 0 | bc
```

It isn't efficient for large lists, but for most of my use cases it is fine. I usually use a shell function to automate the process so that I only have to provide a file name:

```
## cheezy summation
##   call from .bashrc
##
getsum () { echo $(cat $1 | sed 's/$/+/') 0 | bc; }
gethsum () { echo $(cat $1 | sed 's/[gG]/*1000M/' | sed 's/[mM]/*1000K/' | sed 's/[kK]/*1000/' | sed 's/$/+/') 0 | bc; }
gethexsum () { echo ibase=16 $(cat $1 | sed 's/$/+/') 0 | bc; }
```

You can always substitute the end-of-line marker for a specific element separator or character class if your data is delimited in another fashion.

Answer (score 3):

Try piping the output from your grep into

```
awk 'BEGIN {total=0;}{total+=$1;}END {print "Total: ",total}'
```